# How to get webpack hot reload to detect changes in pug + express?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have an Express app with pug and stylus. I've configured the HMR middleware and it reloads on stylus changes but not for pug changes.

I'm wondering if I'm missing a specific configuration. I also tried adding the `pug-html-loader` but that didn't work either.

```
// server.js
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views')); 
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

const webpackDevMiddleware = require('./hmr').dev;
const webpackHotMiddleware = require('./hmr').hot;
app.use(webpackDevMiddleware);
app.use(webpackHotMiddleware);
```

---

```
// hmr.js
const webpackDevMiddleware = require('webpack-dev-middleware');
const webpackHotMiddleware = require('webpack-hot-middleware');

const webpack = require('webpack');
const webpackConfig = require('./webpack.config.js');
const compiler = webpack(webpackConfig);

exports.dev = webpackDevMiddleware(compiler, {
  noInfo: true,
  filename: webpackConfig.output.filename,
  publicPath: webpackConfig.output.publicPath,
  stats: {
    colors: true
  }
});

exports.hot = webpackHotMiddleware(compiler, {
  log: console.log,
  path: '/__webpack_hmr', 
  heartbeat: 10000
});
```

---

```
// webpack.config.js
const javascriptRule = {
  test: /\.js$/,
  use: [
    {
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      options: {
        presets: ['env']
      }
    }
  ]
};

const stylesRule = {
  test: /\.styl$/,
  use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'stylus-loader']
};

module.exports = {
  context: path.join(__dirname, 'javascripts'),
  entry: [
    'webpack-hot-middleware/client?path=/__webpack_hmr&timeout=20000',
    './index.js'
  ],
  devtool: 'source-map',
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/dist/',
    library: 'aux'
  },

  module: {
    rules: [javascriptRule, stylesRule]
  },

  plugins: [new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(), new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin()]
}
```

Comment: Pug is just going to get converted into Javascript in webpack, as such it can't auto load itself, unlike the style-loader, it has built in support for updating with HMR.  To make your Pug files HMR compatible you need to use `if (module.hot) { module.hot.accept( ` etc.  React is another plugin that has built in support of HMR, because Pug is just a templating engine & not a Class/Object component your going to have to handle the HMR yourself.  See here for an example of manually handling HMR ->https://webpack.js.org/guides/hot-module-replacement/

Answer (score 1):

You need install raw-loader: https://webpack.js.org/loaders/raw-loader/

Webpack 3 config:

```
module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.pug$/,
        use: [
          {loader: 'raw-loader'},
          {loader: 'pug-html-loader'}
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    // Templates HTML
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: 'index.html',
      template: './src/templates/index.pug'
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: 'contact.html',
      template: './src/templates/contact.pug'
    }),
    new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
  ]
```

app.js

```
// import all template pug

import 'raw-loader!./templates/index.pug'
import 'raw-loader!./templates/contact.pug'
...
```

That makes webpack listen the changes in the pug files, but it also adds this js code to the bundle.js, then you need to process app.js to clean the bundle.js.